# trying to import excel file using pivot and ssis

Tags: excel, import, ssis, pivot

I am trying to pivot the table to sql server 2008 R2.   with SSIS or t sql code

source excel file is like this.

```
date 1/1/2000 2/1/2000

money    5       7

name Julie      tom
```

I want to make the first column become column names.

```
date money name

1/1/2000 5 Julie

2/1/2000 7 tom
```

what is the easiest way? ssis pivot transformation? SQL code? thank you!

Comment: if it's in excel, can't you do a Paste Special/Transpose?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Power Query (Excel Add-In).  It has an Unpivot Columns command that works the opposite way from most other techniques - it Unpivots all columns **except** the ones you leave unselected.  This just keeps working as more columns are added.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx

You can use Power Query to produce a table in Excel, then point the SSIS Excel Data Source at that to load your SQL table.